# Mapping of line that passes through $a$, $b$ (distinct complex number) using: $z\mapsto \frac{z-a}{z-b} $

Tags: complex-analysis, bilinear-form

I'd like to determine the image of the line through $a$, $b$ (distinct complex number) using the mapping $z\mapsto \frac{z-a}{z-b} $.

What I did so far:

$a\mapsto 0$, and:
$b\mapsto \infty$

Can I conclude something now?

Comment: You need a third point. $\infty$ is also on the original line. What happens to it?

Comment: @WillJagy $\infty\mapsto 1$. So $(a,b,\infty)\mapsto(0,\infty,1)$. So it maps to the positive real axis, right?

Comment: a line or circle is mapped to an entire line or circle under a linear fractional transformation such as you are considering. The image is the entire real axis. With a real parameter $t,$ you ought to be able to calculate what happens to $z = (1-t) a + t b,$ which describes your entire original line.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. For a line segment or circle segment, we would not necessarily have an image that is an entire line or circle right?

Comment: Please do the calculation with $z=(1-t)a + t b.$ And yes, if you deliberately take an arc or segment rather than the full line/circle, you get only part. Including the point $\infty$ in considerations, an L.F.T. is a bijection.

Comment: @WillJagy Ok thank you. I'll do so.